# Cannot get ActionScript 3 to work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, trace

I am sorry for posting such a question, but I have just started using Flash (CS5)  and I can't seem to get a basic trace to work.

Here is the code:

```
package  {

    public class Main {

        public function Main() {

            trace("Hello");

        }
    }
}
```

I have created a new FLA file and saved it in a folder, then I listed Main as the actionscript file that should be linked to the flash file, I also put them in the same folder but when I do (Control -> Test movie -> Test) all i see is a white background without any text on it. Im not sure whats the problem here, is it something to do with including libraries or is there something wrong with the way the script is linked to the flash file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. Trace messages do not show up in the application itself, they show up in the Console.

Comment: I understand, but I don't see anything in the output panel either.

Comment: Did you set the `Document Class` to `Main` in the Properties Panel?

Answer (score 0):

Your main class, in this case called `Main`, needs to extend from `flas.display.Sprite`. Try changing your class to something like this:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite{
        public function Main() {
            trace("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not withing the code itself, when i tried to enter debug mode it said that there isn't an ActionScript associated with the flash file, what is the correct way to link the AS file to the flash file itself? I set the source folder to the one in which the Main class lies but still no results. As i said i also set the class for the file to be Main and it opens the code which i posted here when i open the class with the editor.

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings when running the FLA?

Comment: I get no compiler errors even when I change the code to be incorrect.

Comment: Is your `Main` class a .AS file? See [here](http://i.imgur.com/4bmPEr8.jpg). The `Class` field should say `Main`

Comment: Just for correctness: It doesn't have to be `Sprite`, it has to be a `DisplayObject`. `Sprite` is recommended though.